# How to align text exactly below the image in a grid layout and to make it occupy 2nd line if exceeding the width of the image?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, textview

My XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/signOut"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/gridtext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageMenu"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="#000" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm able to set text exactly below the image in this grid-layout but I also want it to wrap the text to next line if the it is too big. For example, I have an image of "bloodbank" and text is "Nearest Blood-Banks". I want it to be contained within the width of the image. How to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with this one.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/gridtext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageMenu"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageMenu"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageMenu"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:singleLine="false" />
```